integral ring extension implies algebraicity of their fraction fields extension?
$\DeclareMathOperator\Fr{Fr}$There is something I don't get about the following :
Start with the well known fact that if $A\subset B\subset C$ are rings with $B$ the integral closure of $A$ in $C$, then for any multiplicative subset $S\subset A$, $S^{-1}B$ is the integral closure of $S^{-1}A$ in  $S^{-1}C$. (*)
Now suppose $A\subset B$ are integrally closed rings with $B$ integral over $A$. We want to derive from (*) that the fraction field $\Fr(B)$ is an algebraic extension of $\Fr(A)$.
The direct application of (*) taking $C=\Fr(B)$ and $S=A^{*}$ doesn't work since $S^{-1}B$ is smaller than $\Fr(B)$.
Is there a way to do it ?

$(A \setminus \{0\})^{-1}B$ equals $\operatorname{Fr}(B)$.  One containment is obvious.  For the other, fix $b \in B$, and write $M_b(X) \in A[X]$ for the (monic) minimal polynomial of $b$ over $A$.  Then $m_b(X) \mathrel{:=} X^{-1}(M_b(X) - M_b(0))$ lies in $A[X]$, so $b^{-1} = -M_b(0)^{-1}m_b(b)$ lies in $(A \setminus \{0\})^{-1}B$.

Ok thank you. So  the assumption of A and B being integrally closed rings can be weakened by just supposing they are integral domains.
